# Getting the most liked posts

Tags: cakephp

I have a system with posts and likes (correctly linked with models). And I'ld like to get the top liked posts.

After a look in the doc of CakePHP, I found something in the 1.2 doc : `counterCache`. But, it doesn't seems to work anymore with CakePHP 2.x.

So, would you have a solution to get the top liked posts ?

The tables are quite basics : id and created for each and linked with post_id for the likes, here is the `likes` table :

```
========================================
|| *id* | created | post_id | user_id ||
========================================
```

Comment: `counterCache` is still in 2.0 - see [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). But it probably won't be appropriate for you; how are your tables set up/what data do you have to play with. Can't you just `Likes::find('all')` and order by `likes`, with the appropriate level of recursion?

Comment: The idea is, after, having the most popular of the month. But, I don't really see how I can sort bien the posts with the most likes with a `find("all")` :/

Comment: your `likes` table looks like `id, number_of_likes, post_id` right? Each `post hasOne` or `belongsTo` `like` right? You can access the post information via the `like` models associations. Find the `like` record with the most likes (`order by number_of_likes`), there's your `post_id`. from your `post_id` cake will automatically retrieve the associated `post` information.

Comment: Nop, I edited my post with the `likes` table.

Answer (score 0):

Force a join on the posts and likes and query for the `COUNT()` of likes, `GROUP BY` the counter, `ORDER BY` the counter descending, and `LIMIT x` for the top x;

Give a try on this, I assume the models named `Post`, `Like` and a join table:

```
$options = array();
$options['joins'][] = array('table' => 'likes_posts', 'alias' => 'LikePost', 'conditions' => array('LikePost.post_id = Post.id'));
$options['joins'][] = array('table' => 'likes', 'alias' => 'Like', 'conditions' => array('LikePost.like_id = Like.id'));
$options['fields']  = array('COUNT(Like.id) AS counter', 'Post.*');
$options['group']   = 'Like.id';
$options['limit']   = 1; //you could easily get the top 3, top 5, top 10...
$options['order']   = 'counter DESC';
$data = $this->Post->find('all', $options);
$this->set('data', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [CounterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto), but it means replacing the HABTM with a "[hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)"

You would have something like this:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Like');
    // Note that the "posts" table must have a "like_count" integer field
}
class Like extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User',
        'Post' => array('counterCache' => true)
    );
}
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Like');
}
```